# htaccess redirect all traffic to https://www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect three cases to https://www. They are:

`http://`
`http://www`
`https://`

I've been able to get the first two, but not the last one. Here's what I'm using for that:

`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]`
`RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this rule to **add www and turn on https in same rule**:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

To capture value from `%{HTTP_HOST}` you need a condition that is not it `OR` condition.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! It looks like this will convert the first two cases, but not the last pesky one: https:// to https://www

Comment: Of course it will convert `https://domain.com` to `https://www.domain.com`. Make sure to test it first.

Comment: I tried this on my local machine as well as test environment...unfortunately that isn't the case :/  

I did notice if i am at `https://www.domain.com` and remove the www and hit enter, it looks like www is added and then immediately removed.

Comment: **immediately removed** That means you have some other code or rule doing that because this rule is just adding literal `www.` in `RewriteRule`